# manage state with checkbox in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to create this kind of object when check the checkboxes

```
{
"targets": [
    {
      "kind": "foo",
      "channelId": "-897",
      "quote": "true",
      "gatewayName": "bbb"
    },{
      "kind": "bar",
      "channelId": "-1123",
      "quote": "true",
      "gatewayName": "aaa"
     }
   ]
}
```

and I have this snippet for my from

```
{gateways ? gateways.map((g) => {

            return (
              <Tooltip
                key={g.name}
                content={`${g.name} - ${g.kind}`}
              >

                <Switch
                  key={g.name}
                  id={g.name}
                  label={g.name}
                  name={g.name}
                  value={`{"kind":"${g.kind}","channelId":"${g.channelId}","gatewayName":"${g.name}","quote":"true"}`}
                  labelProps={{
                    className: "text-sm font-normal text-blue-gray-500",
                  }}
                  onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                />
              </Tooltip>
            )

}) : "Loading..."}
```

I create the state

```
  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState([]);
```

I'm trying to create the handleCheckboxChange

```
 const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    const { name, checked, value } = e.target;

  
    if(checked){
      setCheckboxes(prev => ({ 
        targets: [prev.targets,JSON.parse(value)]
      }))
    }else{
      setCheckboxes(prev => ({ 
        targets: prev.filter(target => target !== JSON.parse(value))
      }))
    }

    console.log(checkboxes)
  };
```

But when I check the first checkbox I have two element in array, the first is undefined.
when I uncheck I get this error

`TypeError: prev.filter is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is checked you are returning this to your state :

```js
{ targets: [prev.targets, JSON.parse(value)] }
```

This is an object so the state is no longer and array that's why you got

> TypeError: prev.filter is not a function

When you try to uncheck

However, since your state is initialized as `[]` the first check action will not find `prev.targets` so thats why it is `undefined`

If I understood well, you want to store an array of objects, so why you want your state to be an object with only one preoperty `targets` that hold an array ? you can simply make it an array and you know it is representing targets :

```js
if (checked) {
  setCheckboxes((prev) => [...prev, JSON.parse(value)]);
} else {
  setCheckboxes((prev) =>
    prev.filter((target) => JSON.stringify(target) !== JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(value)))
  );
}
```

**Note:** you have to use `JSON.stringify` to compare two objects, otherwise the result is always `false`.

---

But if you insist, what you have to do is to initilize your state this way :

```js
const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({ targets: [] }); // make the property targets exist by default
```

and your code is fine you only have to change this line :

```js
targets: prev.filter(target => target !== JSON.parse(value)) // prev is an object while prev.target is what you need
```

with

```js
targets: prev.targets.filter((target) => JSON.stringify(target) !== JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(value)))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. so how I need to initialize my state? I need to create that kind of object because the server wants it. your snippet code didn't remove the element when I uncheck

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look and give me feedbacks

Comment: thanks for your time. When I select the first element, I get the targets[] with an empty value, when I uncheck I can see what I checked before. If I select another checkbox I have the same behavior. If I select 2 elements I can get targets with one element empty and only one element populated

Comment: This is because you are trying to `console.log` from the wrong place take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75758700/13488990)

Comment: so if you want to see the new value of `checkboxes` you have to log from the JSX not from inside `handleCheckboxChange` because the value of a `useState` hook does not change immediately when you update it but only when the component rerenders

Answer (score 0):

The state for the checkboxes is being initialized as an empty array, however when handling the checkbox change with the function `handleCheckboxChange()` you're setting the state to be an object. So the next time `checked` is changed, `filter` will not be available.

```
if(checked) {
  setCheckboxes(prev => ({ // Returning an OBJECT
    targets: [prev.targets,JSON.parse(value)] 
  }))
}

else { 
                           // also returns an object
  setCheckboxes(prev => ({ // Filter will not be available due to "prev" being an object
    targets: prev.filter(target => target !== JSON.parse(value))
  }))
}
```

Also instead of doing this:

```
value={`{"kind":"${g.kind}","channelId":"${g.channelId}","gatewayName":"${g.name}","quote":"true"}`}
```

You could use object destructuring:

```
value={ { ...g } }
```